# PowerShell - Want to understand why $myarr[(-1)..0] gives 10 1 but $myarr[$myarr[-1]..0] gives expected 10 9 8 ... 0

Tags: arrays, powershell, range, reverse

I want to better understand what is going on here with PowerShell's range operator.

$myArray = 1..10
so we have $myArray with 1 2 3 4 ... 10

Now I want to use -1 to get the last value in the array and show 1 - 10 in reverse, so I do

$myArray[(-1)..0] but this yields only 10 1 (those two values only, nothing in between).

But if I do $myArray[$myArray[-1]..0] this will yield all the values expected 10 9 8 ... 1

Can anyone give an explanation for this? I would think the (-1) being inside [] would evaluate to the last element or value 10 which it seems to be doing then the range would kick in as 10..0 but it seems like the range is being skipped and giving only the two listed values. This is an exercise just to learn PowerShell, there is no specific application of this I'm after. Btw, I get the same 10 1 only if I run the -1 without the ().

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 2):

It is quite simple

Let's see what `-1..0` returns:

```
-1
0
```

So $myArray[-1..0] is equivalent to the $myArray[-1, 0] hence the result.

But the 10..0 expression returns an entire range reversed. Hence the `$myArray[$myArray[-1]..0]` expression works as you would expected.

Comment: So, thinking through this, the range is -1..0 which is essentially two elements and the -1 is being translated into the last element of the array so that is why I'm getting 10 1? So, giving just the -1..0 the range hits first and sees the -1 but by doing the full $myArray[$myArray[-1]..0] the variable gets eval'ed first then the range operator kicks in seeing the 10? So the key seems to be the kind of expression and how it gets eval'ed? Thanks for the explanation. Jason

Comment: See get-help about_operator_precedence. Array index operations get evaluated before range operations.